# Loading MDBootstrap (jquery-version) in Laravel 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, mdbootstrap

I use MDBootstrap in the jquery version for my Laravel 6 project. I downloaded it via NPM and am now trying to integrate it into my project.

The CSS data can be loaded easily by integrating it into the `app.scss` with`@import '~mdbootstrap-pro/css/mdb.min.css';`.

**Loading the JS data does not work**, if I write in my `app.js`,`require ('./../../node_modules/mdbootstrap-pro/js/mdb.min.js');` after running `npm run dev`.

There is no browser error. The MDB-JS code exists in my `app.js`, I checked it. There is no change externally, as if the code was not... there. Mystically.

Here's the crazy one:

If I insert the same file into my HTML document via `<script src =" ./../node_modules/mdbootstrap-pro/js/mdb.min.js "> </script>`, everything works perfectly.

Does anyone have any idea why this is and what I can do there?

---

### Solution

The developers of MDBoostrap know the problem and are already working on a solution. At the moment the `mdb.min.js` has to be added to the project manually. More information here: https://mdbootstrap.com/support/jquery/issue-with-4-9-0-webpack-typescript/